# customize controller using a plugin doesn't work

Tags: magento2, plugin

I want to customize the catalog product view controller using a plugin the following plugin.
In app/etc/di.xml i have added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
     <plugin name="product-view-controller-plugin" type="MyNamespace\MyModule\Controller\Product\View" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Here is View Class:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Controller\Product;
class View {
public function beforeExecute() {

echo "BEFORE<BR>"; exit;

}

public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $controller, $result) { echo "AFTER ...."; exit; }

}
```

when i go to http://mymagento-installation.com/catalog/product/view/id/125 nothing is happening ... can you help me to know what is missing?

Comment: did you flush the cache on magento admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are few thing,you have done wrong.**

### **di.xml location is wrong.**

**di.xml** should be located  at *`app\code\MyNamespace\MyModule\etc\di.xml`*

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
> <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
>    <plugin name="product-view-controller-plugin" type="MyNamespace\MyModule\Controller\Product\View" sortOrder="10"/>
> </type>
> </config>
> ```

### Check Basic files of the module

As you *have created a module* then you *should check  below files should be exits at at ur module*

- **`app\code\MyNamespace\MyModule\composer.json`**
- **`app\code\MyNamespace\MyModule\registration.php`**
- **`app\code\MyNamespace\MyModule\etc\module.xml`**

If this two details is exit then your plugin ***product-view-controller-plugin*** will works

Comment: Thank you Amit, yes di.xml location was wrong